# What is the time difference between Pacific region and Atlantic region?

Tags: timezone

What is the time difference between Pacific region and Atlantic region?

I found answer in http://wiki.answers.com site, and It says 3 hour means AST is 3 hour behind from PST.

**Update:**
I want the correct off set between EST (Eastern time zone) and AST (Atlantic time zone).

I just want to confirm it.

Thanks..

Comment: Wrong place, this is a question for timeoverlow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AST is 1 hour ahead of EST.

Get help from GMT offset provided in my OS (windows).

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically mean the timezones AST and PST (rather than the broader definition of "Atlantic Region" and "Pacific region", then:

- [AST](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/ast.html) is currently UTC - 4 hours.
- [PST](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/pst.html) is currently UTC - 8 hours.

So the time difference is currently 4 hours (i.e. AST is four hours ahead of PST).